# aws_codepipeline inside cdk-pipelines, how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm exploring how to do CI/CD using cdk-pipelines, but while the setup part works, I don't understand the control part. All the examples are really [simple inline code Lambda Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html).

How do I "release a change" of a `codepipeline.Pipeline` inside a `cdk_pipelines`?

```js
const cdk_pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(...)
cdk_pipeline.addStage(new BuildImageTestStage(...))

// build-image-test-stage.ts
new BuildImageTestStack(...)

// build-image-test-stack.ts
const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(...)
pipeline.addStage(...CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction...)
pipeline.addStage(...CodeBuildAction...)
```

It sets up the pipeline just fine, but it doesn't fire off the actual codepipeline itself.

Options that I see:

- `codepipeline.Pipelines(triggerOnPush: true)` - doesn't work because I want the cloud formation to run first THEN build+test. Trigger on push effectively runs parallel.
- Completely separate setup from code deployment by using `codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction`

Unsure option:

- `cdk_pipeline.addStage(..., { post: [] })` - CDK Pipeline post to trigger a code deploy, but I'm unsure on how to "wait" for it to finish.

Separately, I wish cdk-pipelines were named differently than codepipeline. It's just so hard to search.

Comment: The `CodePipeline` construct creates a [AWS::CodePipeline::Pipline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html) resource and a trigger (Webhook/EventBridge) that starts the pipeline execution when there is a change to its [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#synth-and-sources).  That's not what you want?

Comment: @fedonev while possible, I want to "wait" for the deploy to finish. Basically 2 different steps, `build || test image`, parallel and then run `migration, deploy` serial. I always could do a cli `aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution` and then poll `aws codepipeline get-pipeline-execution` for status, but that's pretty janky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit after exchanges in the comments]:  `pipeline.CodePipeline` is a wrapper for a `codepipeline.Pipeline`. It creates a new `codepipeline.Pipeline` under the hood in its construtor.  The `const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(...)` line is adding a *second* `codepipeline.Pipeline`.  You almost certainly don't want two.  You have a few options:

**Option 1:**  Pass `codePipeline: pipeline` in the `cdk_pipeline` constructor.  `cdk_pipeline` will use your `codepipeline.Pipeline` [instead of creating its own](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#using-an-existing-aws-codepipeline).

**Option 2:**  Get rid of your `pipeline` instance.  Refactor your build/test actions as [pre or post Steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.AddStageOpts.html) in the options for `cdk_pipline.addStage` or `addWave`.  A [CodeBuildStep](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodeBuildStep.html) will add a build step, for example.  You can [add arbitrary CodePipeline actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#arbitrary-codepipeline-actions) as steps, too.

---

AWS pipeline executions always run from beginning to end, each step "waiting" for the next to finish (except if stopped by an error).  A CDK `pipeline.CodePipeline` always starts with the source action defined in its [synth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#synth-and-sources) property.

The [addStage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#cdk-application-deployments) method adds a serial stage to the pipeline.  To add parallel stages, use [addWave](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#deploying-in-parallel).

A CDK [pipeline.CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html) makes it easy to create a pipeline that deploys CDK apps.  It abstracts away the details of the more general-purpose [codepipeline.Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline-readme.html). If your use case is something other than building/testing/deploying CDK apps, though, you may be better off working directly with the latter, as the [docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#cdk-pipelines).

Comment: > If your use case is something other than building/testing/deploying CDK apps. Yeah I'm trying to deploy a CDK app + a Python Docker Lambda, which seems like this isn't a great use case for.

Comment: @nitsujri  It's a \*perfect\* fit for that use case.  You are using the [aws_lambda_python_alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha/README.html) constructs, right?

Comment: I'm using Django ASGI, [Mangun](https://mangum.io/), a `buildspec.yml` creates a Docker Image to ECR, ImageUri is passed to cdk's `serverless.CfnFunction`. The CodePipeline for that works great but to wrap the CodePipeline with a CDK Pipelines without being janky is where I'm stuck.

Comment: how do I do that? [cdk_pipeline.addStage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_pipelines.CodePipeline.html#addwbrstagestage-options) takes a CDK.Stage construct which is another Stack vs [CodePipeline.addStage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.Pipeline.html#addwbrstageprops) takes StageOptions

Comment: @nitsujri I added 2 options in the edited answer.

Comment: incredible! thanks so much. Def going with option 1